# First eigenfunction of $p=3$-Laplacian of a square domain in $\Bbb R^2$ : reference for any work on this?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, elliptic-pde, p-laplace, nonlinear-eigenvalue

In the last few decades, lots of work on first eigenfunction of $p$-Laplace with Dirichlet and other boundary conditions. But I couldn't find much on periodic boundary conditions. I have computed the first eigenfunction for $p=3$, square domain in $\Bbb R^2$. I have shown it as a grey scale image below. One period I tiled in the plane ($4\times 4$ tiles) to illustrate its meeting periodic boundary conditions.

[image]

I wonder such a simple structure not have a closed form expression. Can we guess anything on its closed form expression? Any reference to work in this direction (especially in dimension greater than $1$.)

Color picture :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_p(x)$ be the first eigenfunction of $p$-Laplacian for the domain $(0,1)$ under periodic boundry conitions. Then, for all $p\ge(d+1)$ it can be shown that $$u(\vec{x}) = g_p( \vec{x}\cdot\vec{z}), z \in \mathbb{Z}^d,$$ is an eigenfunction for the $p$-Laplacian for the domain $(0,1)^d$ under periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: It is mentioned in loc.cit. that $\sin_3$ is the eigenfunction of the 3-Laplacian, so maybe the non-trivial part of the question is to show that this is the eigenfunction with the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: @FanZheng : That was for the case 1 dimension. For 2 dimensions or greater,  there hasnt been an analytic form discovered for any non trivial eigenfunctions till date, let alone first.

Comment: which brings me to this question: does it work if I just lift the 1-dimensional eigenfunction to the torus, say $\sin_3(x)$ regarded as a function of two variables?

Comment: @FanZheng : I am at a loss. I really don't know what you are saying, and also I don't know differential geometry. So I cannot get any interpretation of what you are saying and its intent. If its simple enough, you may explain. From my point of view, I am interested only square domains in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$. So probably it may help me if you can explain a bit.

Comment: OK. Maybe I have used a little fancy terminology, but I'm really trying to say: Way don't you try $u(x,y)=\sin_3x$ (with appropriate scaling)? BTW, it seems that you missed a factor of $\sqrt2$ or something in the above computation. If that is the case, then $\sin_3x$ would have a smaller eigenvalue.

Comment: @FanZheng : I dont have time right now, so will do it later. But I think you are right. The first eigenfunction is a minimizer of Rayleigh quotient. So if you dont vary along $y$-axis then probably you get a smaller norm for the gradient. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I spoke to a few researchers and they all said there isn't (atleast not known) an analytic form for eigenfunctions in dimensions greater than 1.

Comment: @FanZheng : I have edited. Appreciate your comments.

Comment: That's what I mean, but I don't see why you need $p\ge d+1$.

Comment: @FanZheng : As per this link, this is an open problem (not only first, but any): https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ade/1356651224 Wonder why? if its such a simple thing. Am I certainly missing something here? Any ideas are appreciated. As to the $p>=d+1$, you may relax it, I had kept it without much attention as I am interested only in $p>=d+1$ as a part of some other problem.

Comment: As far as what I got from the introduction of the paper, it seems to be considering an ODE of a vector valued function (i.e. $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^d$), not quite the same as your problem.

Comment: @FanZheng : Agree. Do you know any paper where the above solution is used for scalar valued functions. I know its simple and expected, but I know want to know if it has already used by someone, as some people said that it is open and I am not able to find one on google or ZbMath. I dont have access to MathSciNet.